# How to connect to websocket from remote ip

Tags: websocket, tornado

I created web socket test app with tornado server and static html page for check connection to this server.

When I try to connect from localhost to websocket, it works fine. if I try to connect from remote IP, I get "connection closed by timeout".

`netstat -lnp` gives me next result:

```
tcp    0      0 0.0.0.0:8080        0.0.0.0:*         LISTEN      14837/python2.7
```

Comment: Assuming your WebSocket server runs on 192.168.1.100:8080, try opening http://192.168.1.100:8080 in your browser (entering the adress into browser adress bar) .. to verify basic connectivity.